# Is every Hausdorff sequential space monolithic?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

A space $X$ called monolithic if for any subset $A$ with $|A|\le \kappa$, then $nw(\overline{A})\le \kappa$. Is every Hausdorff sequential space monolithic?

What I have tried: For any subset $A$, because $nw(\overline{A})\le|\overline{A}|\le [A]^\omega=\kappa$, then it is true. Am I right?

Comment: What is $nw(A)$? I don't know this notation.

Comment: Like the base of $A$, but the element not need be open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Mrówka space $\Psi$](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/) is a counterexample: it’s even first countable, but it’s a separable space with net weight $2^\omega$. Your mistake is in thinking that $\left|[A]^\omega\right|$ must equal $|A|$. Suppose that $A$ is countably infinite: then $\left|[A]^\omega\right|=2^\omega$, not $\omega$.

Comment: Could you tell me what is wrong in my proof?

Comment: @Paul: Sorry $-$ I meant to put that in my answer and forgot. I’ll add it now.